# Is there any way at all to make a simple and custom HTML/CSS email signature in gmail?

Tags: html, css

All I'm trying to do is make a simple HTML and CSS email signature for gmail. I minify the code so it fits in the signature box.

The code is as follows:

```
    <html>
  <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
        <style type="text/css">
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@300;700&display=swap");
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="width: 450px; height: 300px; margin: 0">
    <div class="name-grid" style="padding-left: 5px">
      <p
        class="name"
        style="
          color: #abd590;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
          font-weight: 700;
          margin-bottom: -12px;
        "
      >
        David Seamen
      </p>
      <p class="title" style="font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif">
        graphic designer
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      class="contact-grid"
      style="
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 25px 100px;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 22px);
        align-items: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 5px;
      "
    >
      <p
        class="green"
        style="
          color: #abd590;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
      >
        m
      </p>
      <a
        href="tel:+02020123123145"
        style="
          text-decoration: none;
          color: grey;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
        class="contact"
        >152345125125</a
      >
      <p
        class="green"
        style="
          color: #abd590;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
      >
        e
      </p>
      <a
        href="mailto:design@david.com"
        style="
          text-decoration: none;
          color: grey;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
        class="contact"
        >design@david.com</a
      >
      <p
        class="green"
        style="
          color: #abd590;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
      >
        w
      </p>
      <a
        class="contact"
        style="
          text-decoration: none;
          color: grey;
          font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        "
        href="https://www.mrdavid.com</a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img
        src="https://drive.google.com/XXX"
        alt="Logo"
        style="width: 25rem; padding-left: 5px"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway at all to get something like this as a signature?

Or are we limited to the crappy editor? How do those cool email peoples get those badass email signatures with all of the links etc? It always seems as though they have used code?

Thanks :)